# Aggregated row count differences between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, aggregate-functions

I have two MySQL tables A and B both with this schema

| ID | entity_id | asset | asset_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12345 | x | 1 |
| .. | ......... | ..... | .......... |

I would like to get an aggregated top 10/50/whatever `entity_ids` with the largest row count difference between the two tables. I *think* I could do this manually by just getting the highest row count by `entity_id` like so

```
select count(*), entity_id
-> from A
-> group by entity_id
-> order by count(*) desc;
```

and just manually comparing to the same query for table B but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in just one query, that compares row counts for each distinct `entity_id` and aggregates the differences between row counts. A few notes

- There is an index on `entity_id` for both tables
- Table B will always have an equivalent or greater number of rows for each `entity_id`

Sample output

| entity_id | difference |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 100 |
| 3232 | 75 |
| 5992 | 40 |
| and so on | for top 10/50 |

Comment: Are there any `entity_id`s that exist in only 1 table?

Comment: No – I'm confident that the only difference between these tables should be the number of rows for any given `entity_id`

Comment: please provide sample output....entity id wise count for both table and their difference...if difference is negative then...

Comment: Apologies @RahulBiswas I added an output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate in each table and join the results to get the difference:

```
SELECT a.entity_id, b.counter - a.counter diff
FROM (SELECT entity_id, COUNT(*) counter FROM A GROUP BY entity_id) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT entity_id, COUNT(*) counter FROM B GROUP BY entity_id) b
ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
ORDER BY diff DESC LIMIT 10
```